# How do I launch a Beanstalk environment with HealthChecks as "EC2 and ELB" and health_check_grace_time as 1500 using terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have started learning about terraform recently and wanted to create an environment using the above stated settings. When I run the below code I get 2 resources deployed one is beanstalk and other is Auto Scaling group(ASG) the ASG has the desired settings but is not linked with the beanstalk . Hence I am trying to Connect these two.
(I copy the beanstalk Id form the Tags section then head over to ASG under EC2 and search for the same and look at the health Check section)

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example" {
  launch_configuration = aws_launch_configuration.as_conf.id
  min_size = 2
  max_size = 10
  availability_zones = [ "us-east-1a" ]
  
  health_check_type = "ELB"
  health_check_grace_period = 1500
  tag {
    key = "Name"
    value = "terraform-asg-example"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
}


resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_application" "application" {
  name        = "Test-app"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "environment" {
  name                = "Test-app"
  application         = aws_elastic_beanstalk_application.application.name
  solution_stack_name = "64bit Windows Server Core 2019 v2.5.6 running IIS 10.0"

  setting {
        namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
        name      = "IamInstanceProfile"
        value     = "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
      }

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autscaling"
  }
}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "as_conf" {
  name          = "web_config_shivanshu"
  image_id      = "ami-2757f631"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it how we can change the Auto-scaling group(ASG) of the beanstalk we have created using terraform. First of all,create the beanstalk according to your setting. we use the  [Setting](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elastic_beanstalk_environment) block in beanstalk resource and [Namespace](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html) for configuring it according to our need.

Step-1
Create a beanstalk using terraform

```
    resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "test"
   { ...
     ...    
   }
```

Step-2
After you have created the beanstalk.Create autoscaling resource skeleton. the ASG associated with the beanstalk will be handled by terraform under this resource block.[Import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) using the id of ASG that you can get from either terraform plan/show

```
terraform import aws_autoscaling_group.<Name that you give> asg-id
```

Step-3
After you have done that Change the beanstalk according to your [need](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/autoscaling_group)
then make sure you have added these to tags.Because sometimes I have noticed that the mapping of this ASG to the beanstalk is is lost.

```
     tag {
           key                 = "elasticbeanstalk:environment-id" 
           propagate_at_launch = true 
           value               = aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.<Name of your beanstalk>.id
        }
      tag {
           key                 = "elasticbeanstalk:environment-name" 
           propagate_at_launch = true 
           value               = aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment.<Name of your beanstalk>.name
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not create an ASG or launch config/template outside of the Elastic Beanstalk environment and join them together. As there are config options which are not available. For example GP3 SSD is available as part of a launch template, but not available as part of elastic beanstalk yet

What you want to do is remove the resources of

```
resource "aws_launch_configuration" "as_conf"
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "example"
```

Then utilise the `setting {}` block a lot more within `resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "environment"`

Here is a list of all the settings you can describe in the settings block (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options-general.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I came across the Link you shared but i could not find a way were i can set health checks as ELB and EC2 under the auto scaling of the beanstalk. basically i want to configure the auto scaling part of the beanstalk. Can you help me figure out how to do that using the setting block

Comment: Take a look at  Namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:process:default under HealthCheckPath

Comment: What elastic beanstalk settings have you tried?

Comment: Did you see the image that i posted? So basically i tried the Health check path one but its still deploying with only EC2 as health check